# Should I prevent JavaScript injections in password field?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-injection, html-injections

I've found lots of information about JavaScript injections, but didn't find any specific regarding `password` field.

For my test GMail account I was able to set the next password `<Script>alert(document.cookie);</script>`  and it works correctly.
[image]
[image]

Should I just encode the `<` and `>` to their HTML equivalent?

How to handle such passwords?

**Edit #1:**
I store passwords in DB as hashes (and no issues for JavaScript injections here). 
And I want to add a toggle for Password Visibility. 
In this case I should encode the `<` and `>` to their HTML equivalent and that's it?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the plain text of a password, so there should be no worries of JavaScript injections in password fields.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to protect against. HTML characters don't have any meaning in the `value` attribute. You also shouldn't be displaying the password in the first place.

Comment: You should be able to set pretty much any input to something that looks like script injection. It’s your responsibility to encode it appropriately whenever you move it somewhere else (like when creating HTML). Also, after being aware of how it works, use a template engine that escapes automatically so you don’t have to worry about it.

Comment: Form parameters aren't interpreted by the client, they can contain any characters.

Comment: @Barmar am I right that I should just store hash (using key derivation function) of password in DB and I don't need to do any other handling?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way to do it. But it has nothing to do with JavaScript injection, which can only happen when you display user-provided data on a web page.

Comment: A password can only become involved in JS injection if you save it in clear text (or with reversible encryption), have a web page that displays passwords, and you don't encode it properly when displaying.

Comment: @Barmar could please check my update for this question?

Comment: You toggle password visibility by changing the input field from `type="password"` to `type="text"`. It doesn't require fetching the password from the DB.

Comment: If the "show password" option on the page is implemented with a plain `<input>`, you don't have to do anything at all; just update its value. If you're going to show the password as the contents of a `<span>` or something, then you have to HTML-encode it (and note that you also have to worry about `&` characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I used the next advice:**

1. you should store passwords in DB as hashes (no issues for JavaScript injections here).
2. for a `Password toggle Visibility`:

   2.1 if it is implemented with a plain `<input>`, you don't have to do anything (no JavaScript injections here).

   2.2 if it is implemented with a `<span>`, `<div>`, etc, then you have to HTML-encode it (and note that you also have to worry about `&` characters).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Password: <input type="password" value="<Script>alert(document.cookie);</script>" id="myInput"><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="showPasswd()">Show Password

<script>
function showPasswd() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if (x.type === "password") {
x.type = "text";
  } else {
x.type = "password";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```